# Flask raises TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a REST API using Python Flask which receives XML files via POST.
I would like the API to read the contents of the XML, and look for one parameter/key ("Directory"), to decide where to send it onwards, like a switchboard to other web apps.

The main issue is that I keep getting 500 errors when using the Flask request.data or request.form - one of these methods should work with XML, according to other similar posts.

Common 500 error explanation is "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."

I've tried command line cURL requests based off other StackOverflow threads to send one XML at a time, but no difference compared to the client python program I wrote to send XMLs (using requests libary).

## XML format I've been using to cURL to the API

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
> <xml>
> <Directory>Directory 2</Directory>
> <ID>2</ID>
> <Name>Jane</Name>
> </xml>
> ```

## Python Flask API Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import xmltodict
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/XMLhandling", methods=["POST"])
def handleXML():
    #for debugging..
    if True:
        print("HEADERS", request.headers)
        print("REQ_path", request.path)
        print("ARGS", request.args)
        print("DATA", request.data)
        print("FORM",request.form)
    #parse the XML
    datacache = xmltodict.parse(request.form)
    print(datacache)
    print(datacache['xml']['Directory'])
    if datacache['xml']['Directory'] == "Directory 1":
        requests.post("http://localhost:25565/XML",data = xml)
    elif datacache['xml']['Directory'] == "Directory 2":
        requests.post("http://localhost:50001/XML",data = xml)
    else:
        return 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)
```

Happy to provide extra info if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the view does not return a [valid response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses).

The code in the question returns either `400` if it can't find the directory or `None` if it succeeds (Python functions return `None` if there is no explicit `return` statement at the end of a function).  Neither of these values are valid responses.

As this is an API we only care about returning an HTTP status code, but Flask requires that we supply a response too: in this case we can use an empty string for the response body.

In the error case we return

```
'', 400
```

and in the success case

```
'', 200
```

(if we just return a string the status code will default to `200`, returning an explicit code shows our intent).

This code should work:

```
@app.route("/XMLhandling", methods=["POST"])
def handleXML():
    #for debugging..
    if True:
        print("HEADERS", request.headers)
        print("REQ_path", request.path)
        print("ARGS", request.args)
        print("DATA", request.data)
        print("FORM",request.form)
    #parse the XML
    datacache = xmltodict.parse(request.form)
    print(datacache)
    print(datacache['xml']['Directory'])
    if datacache['xml']['Directory'] == "Directory 1":
        requests.post("http://localhost:25565/XML",data = xml)
    elif datacache['xml']['Directory'] == "Directory 2":
        requests.post("http://localhost:50001/XML",data = xml)
    else:
        # Return empty response body and status code.
        return '', 400
    # Returning empty body with no status code would work here too.
    return '', 200
```